# confirmation token invalid in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I tried the solutions already suggested on stackoverflow, but with no success.  Here's the situation.  I'm building a Rails app using Devise for authentication.  In development, I was able to get the confirmation via email link to work just fine.  I signed up, an email was sent, and I clicked the link which redirected me to the app, and I, the user, was confirmed.  However, in production on the Heroku platform, this method of User sign up confirmation fails.  Specifically, I get the message

"1 error prohibited this user from being saved.

Confirmation token invalid"

In the Heroku log when I get "Confirmation token invaled", I noticed that the confirmation token that is generated when the User is created (ee438ce80d3cc139df595771f8e058cc2eb7a91b33429d30c1ae6e4b3b00721f) is different from the confirmation token in the "Confirm my account" link sent by Devise: http://bloccit.herokuapp.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=GvdY2xffANGxEndv8Nc_

I tried the replace the tokens with each other, (replacing GvdY2xffANGxEndv8Nc_ with ee438ce80d3cc139df595771f8e058cc2eb7a91b33429d30c1ae6e4b3b00721f in the URL, and also "ee438ce80d3cc139df595771f8e058cc2eb7a91b33429d30c1ae6e4b3b00721f" with "GvdY2xffANGxEndv8Nc_" in the Production Database) still no luck!

Then, I was made aware of some modifications people made in the devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb view.  I experimented and changed the file

from

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

to

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Also, I read Devise documentation stating that Confirmation registration is no longer advisable. But, the documentation continues, if you want to use it, include the following setting in the devise.rb file:

> config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true

I followed the instructions and made the changes to the view I mentioned.  Then committed to git, and re-deployed to Heroku.  I found that this generated the same confirmation tokens in the User object instance AND in the "Confirm my account".  Look at the Heroku log:

> 2015-04-17T03:53:40.460157+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["confirmation_token", "aa160f928b848bb06d9c5a681dafdc00333904d9e012dd95b1b344d9c7aff20c"]]
>    ...
>   2015-04-17T03:53:40.905542+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> You can confirm your account email through the link below:
>
> 2015-04-17T03:53:40.905533+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
>   2015-04-17T03:53:40.905544+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2015-04-17T03:53:40.905545+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> `<a href="http://bloccit.herokuapp.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=aa160f928b848bb06d9c5a681dafdc00333904d9e012dd95b1b344d9c7aff20c">Confirm my account</a></p>`

However, I got the same error I noted above "Confirmation token invalid."

I've been working on this for over two evenings.  I also don't understand why no error in development, but error in production arghhh!

Viral

Comment: looks like some of my stuff got stripped out.

Comment: looks like some of my stuff got stripped out--changed from

Comment: changed from  <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>  TO <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>

Comment: for better readability, here's the confirm my account link: <a href="http://bloccit.herokuapp.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=aa160f928b848bb06d9c5a681dafdc00333904d9e012dd95b1b344d9c7aff20c">

Comment: what is the version of Devise?

Comment: I didn't specify a version in the Gem file.  I wrote: "gem 'devise'"

Comment: If it works locally and not in production then i guess both are using different versions. Manually specify the version, get it to run locally and then try on heroku

Comment: then, used "bundle" to install.  did some configuring for my environment.  Also, included the following in the config directory, in the development.rb file: config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

Comment: None of the above is in the production.rb file.  I'm new to web dev, so I'm often shooting in the dark.  thanks for taking interest.

Comment: I'll try what you suggest and get back to you later. thanks Mandeep!

Comment: It's normal for the token in the URL and the token in the db to be different: the one in the db is hashed (since devise 3 I believe)

Comment: specified the version of 'devise', '3.4.1'--still no success!  stuck.  also, tried to confirm via email in development just now, and it doesn't work!!!  Makes me think there is something wrong not just with my code.

Comment: I was able to get confirmation via email to work again in development.  I had toset my config secret key to a fixed token.  I think that was the reason it didn't work the last time in development.  Still won't work in production, wonder if it has something to do with reading the environment to get the value for the config secret variable.

Comment: Thanks Frederick, didn't realize that.

Comment: In my development environment just now, confirmation by email works fine.

Comment: @chinoxxl, is your Heroku app named bloccit? I am pretty sure that is the one that Bloc uses for the example project. I think what may be happening is you are being sent to Bloc's example project to confirm the registration instead of your app.

Comment: @AlexS.I think you're right.  In my production.rb , I have  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'bloccit.herokuapp.com'}  Let me change the host to the proper URL, and see what happens. I can tell you know that I will feel really stupid if that makes it work.

Comment: @AlexS.You were right.  Thanks so much!  Yes, I do feel stupid.

Comment: @chinoxxl No worries! It happens to the best of us. I'll throw up an answer so you can mark it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` is set to `{ host: 'bloccit.herokuapp.com' }`. This is the example project provided by Bloc. In order for the confirmation token to work, you'll just need to set this as `{ host: 'your_app_name.herokuapp.com' }`.